# Where to create package environment variables?

Tags: r, environment-variables, r-package

I'm doing a data analysis and created a package to store my vignettes and data, as explained [here](https://rmflight.github.io/posts/2014/07/vignetteAnalysis.html).

I want to set some variables that would be available to all my package functions.

These variables define: the path to data sets, the measurements characteristics (such as probes positions), physical constants and so on.

I have read that one recommended way to store such variables is to use environments.

The question is, where do I put the script that creates the environment?

I thought about putting it in the onLoad method, to be sure it's executed when the package is loaded.

Comment: Regarding paths, you could define them as options retrieving each with `getOption` or as environment variables retrieving each with `Sys.getenv` and defining their values in your `.Rprofile`.  This would make your package independent of the particular paths on your machine.  If making it only semi-independent is ok then you could hard code a default configuration so that initially nothing need be set in your `.Rprofile` yet you could still change them without modifying the package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you put it in the `.onLoad` function (not method), you'll have to use the `assign` function to ensure the environment gets created in your package namespace.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname)
{
    # ...
    assign("myPackageEnvironment", new.env(), parent.env())
    # ...
}
```

But you can also just put it in open code:

```
myPackageEnvironment <- new.env()
```

Informally, you can think of your package's .R files as being `source`d one after another into the environment of your package namespace. So any statements that run in open code will create objects there directly.

Comment: This means I could even just declare my variables in an R file (not in an environment) and use them in my package functions?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Objects created in the package namespace are locked, so you can't change their values after loading. The thing with environments is that while the _environment object_ is locked, its _contents_ are still modifiable.

Comment: But if my variables are constant, not supposed to be changed after package loading, that could work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Let me rephrase. Objects in the package namespace are locked _at compile time_, so they can't be changed when the user loads the package. This means you can store static objects like functions, class definitions etc, but not anything that is determined at runtime.