# How to change package logic to avoid modifying .GlobalEnv

Tags: r, global-variables, assign, r-package, cran

**Background.** I am writing a package that I'd like to submit to CRAN (called [surveytable](https://cdcgov.github.io/surveytable/)). The basic logic of the package is:

To start, the user specifies an object that they want to work with. In this example, the object is called `"namcs2019sv"`.

```r
library(surveytable)
set_survey("namcs2019sv")
```

Other functions in the package work with this object. Some functions analyze the object (but do not modify it):

```r
tab("AGER")
```

Other functions modify the object. Here, `var_cross()` creates a new variable inside the object called `"Age x Sex"`. `tab()` can then be used to analyze this new variable.

```r
var_cross("Age x Sex", "AGER", "SEX")
tab("Age x Sex")
```

**.GlobalEnv.** The way I accomplish this is by using `.GlobalEnv`. Every function that deals with the object calls `get0()` at the beginning to get the object. The functions that need to modify the object (like `var_cross()`), at the end of the function call `assign()`.

When you call assign, you have to specify the environment that you are assigning to. Thus, I used to have `assign(*, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. I read that CRAN doesn't want you to do that, so I changed it to `assign(*, envir = getOption("surveytable.survey_envir"))`, where the `"surveytable.survey_envir"` option is set to `.GlobalEnv`.

CRAN does not like this. They write, "Please do not modify the .GlobalEnv. This is not allowed by the CRAN policies."

**Question.** How can I change my package to comply with the CRAN policy?

The usual approach is to specify the object as an argument in each function call, and to return it for the functions that modify it, like this:

```r
tab("AGER", object = namcs2019sv)
namcs2019sv = var_cross("Age x Sex", "AGER", "SEX", object = namcs2019sv)
tab("Age x Sex", object = namcs2019sv)
```

I don't want to do this. The whole purpose of setting up the package the way it currently is, is to make tasks easier for users of the package. The intended user just wants to specify the object of interest once, and then they want to issue lots of commands to analyze and / or modify the object. They don't want to keep typing and retyping the object name on every line.

Another approach is, at the beginning of every function, when I call `get0()`, to also figure out which environment the object is coming from, and then to `assign()` it to that environment.

When I looked into this, I've found conflicting solutions online, which appear to work sometimes but not others. I have not found a solution as part of a package that I can just use.

Even if I were to do this, I don't know whether it would comply with the CRAN policy though. If I figure out which environment the object is coming from, then I `assign()` to it, and the environment turns out to be `.GlobalEnv`, then I think this still contradicts their policy, doesn't it?

Comment: I honestly believe you should re-think your design. R already has mechanisms to prevent re-typing variable names (that's what the pipe `|>` is for). Your design is convenient in this one marginal sense, but difficult in a few others - 1) It is a fairly alien way of working that will be unintuitive to many existing R users, 2) It sounds like you could only work with one data set at a time, which limits the user 3) The user has to pass strings instead of unquoted names, 4) It would not extend well or mesh with other packages well, and 5) CRAN doesn't like it.

Comment: But if you really want to do this, one solution would be for your package to have its own environment. You can define an environment in your package as you can with any other object. Using _that_ as a workspace would be acceptable to CRAN.

Comment: @AllanCameron How would that work? I have not worked with environments before. Could you give a simple example or link to a package that does this? 

Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954302/where-to-create-package-environment-variables

Comment: yes, just like is shown in the answer to that question. You can set or get objects from you environment inside your functions, like `mypackageenv$data <- result`. Then `mypackageenv$data` will be available to other functions in your package.

Comment: But seriously, _please_ rethink your design here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @AllanCameron 's advice, I added an environment to the package.

Specifically, all you do is just add the line

```
env = new.env()
```

somewhere in [your package's `zzz.R`](https://github.com/CDCgov/surveytable/blob/master/R/zzz.R#L20) file.

When the user gives me the object that I wish to use / modify later, I just [save it to this environment](https://github.com/CDCgov/surveytable/blob/master/R/set_survey.R#L63):

```
env$object = object
```

When I need to ["get" the object](https://github.com/CDCgov/surveytable/blob/master/R/set_survey.R#L78): `object = env$object`. Make changes to `object`, then [save it back to the package's environment](https://github.com/CDCgov/surveytable/blob/master/R/var_any.R#L33): `env$object = object`.

Once you see this pattern, it is so easy.